# Nivo Slider thumbnail loading incorrect images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nivo-slider

Here is the page I am working on: 
http://symmetrypilates.net/studio/studio1.html

Here is the css:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5591635/

Nature of the problem:

The images will load the previously clicked image instead of the one clicked immediately.

How can I fix this to make the image that is clicked load into the larger view?

Comment: problem is not in css. If i can see your javascript part of the page then i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think no errors with css,Error is with your page itself.Recheck the path set for thumbnail and path for the larger image for the same thumbnail. This type of issue occurs only when conflicting paths are there.

Comment: Those were all fine, the client didn't want thumbnails anyway. I fixed it all up.

Comment: I am having a problem with nivo slider. It wasn't doing this on saturday, but for some reason it's doing this again: it will not load the image that you click on, and after you click on a second one, then it will load the first one you clicked :: http://symmetrypilates.net/studio/studio1.html (html : http://paste.ubuntu.com/5616582/) (css: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5616584/ )

Answer (score 0):

looking into your source code it may be a problem try it in `$.document.ready()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: false,
        controlNavThumbs:true,
        controlNavThumbsFromRel:true,
 pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: true, // Force manual transitions
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: for some reason when I have $(document).ready(function() or $(window).ready(function() the images don't load at all